# Careers is not allowing me to add custom answers

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs

When I go to my careers profile and then hit "Add an answer" and paste this link: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10756634/js-missing-integer/10756881](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10756634/js-missing-integer/1075688)

It says:

> The link you provided does not lead to a stackexchange answer by you. Please try again.

The answer is by me, and my stack overflow account is linked to my careers profile correctly.  I've added answers this way in the past before.  Is anyone else experiencing this?  I suspect it might be a bug.

[Here is my profile](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/pauloldridge)

Comment: +1: having exactly the same issue and it just happened to me about 12 hours ago (even if using the proposed link format below). I duplicated the question here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/133865/173947 (now closed). Maybe you should add the "bug" tag to your question.

Comment: A peculiar similarity I find between your issue and mine is that we are both in Canada (BC) ... a proxy issue? odd.

Comment: I'm having the same issue!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a bug on my part.  I updated the logic for this widget last week and there are 2 cases, 1) you link to the question and it loops all answers looking for any that belong to you and 2) you link directly to your answer.

Case 1 was working just fine, case 2 I had inverted logic and needed to add a not.  This 1 character change set should be out shortly.

Comment: Funny, It looks like you earned positive reputation from a bug you made... `:)`

Comment: I guess they up voted his honesty ;)

Comment: And dont forget to add `www` after `http://`

Answer (score 5):

That link doesn't look right, it doesn't even get you to your answer if you click on it.

Try any of these:

- `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10756634/js-missing-integer/10756881#10756881`
- `http://stackoverflow.com/a/10756881/772035`

Comment: Neither of those are working for me either right now.

Comment: @paul Hm, that's weird, I've added some answers myself earlier today and it worked just fine.

Comment: good answer, but it doesn't solve the issue. it seems like a bug.

Comment: @JFK Yes it probably is.

Answer (score 1):

I just discovered that if I try to add the answer using only the question portion of the url:

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10756634/js-missing-integer
```

It works correctly. I'm not sure how the systems decides which answer to pick if you've answered the same question twice, but I don't think that will ever cause me any issues.

---

Since the system expects only the url to a question, that should probably be made more clear, or it should automatically strip off the end of the url to determine which question you mean.

An interesting thing to note is that the error message changes slightly depending on the url:

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10756634/js-missing-integer/10756881#10756881
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10756634/js-missing-integer/10756881
```

Both give me:

> The link you provided does not lead to a stackexchange answer by you. Please try again.

But if I strip a few more characters off:

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10756634/js-missing-integer/1075688
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10756634/js-missing-integer/10
```

I get a different error message:

> The link you provided does not lead to a valid StackExchange answer. Please try again.

Any url between these two seems to work fine:

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10756634
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10756634/js-missing-integer/
```